# Is there party level balancing?

Tags: the-division

If I'm level 21 and I join a party of 1 or more low level players will that make the game harder or near impossible for them?

e.g. Make enemy levels higher than their level?

I'm aware more enemies will spawn simply from having another party member but will it make them tougher because of the level difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience as a level 4-6 player playing with my level 26 nephew is that as soon as we grouped, all missions showed as level 21 and encounters or enemies we ran into on the street were high level too since they would kill me with one shot.

From reading comments on another answer I'm thinking the level will be somewhere between the levels of the players, but not less  than 5 levels lower than the highest level player.

I did leave the group (caused a reloading wait screen) and start a side mission, then invited my nephew.  In this instance, the enemies were still low level, but they had already spawned, and as soon as the mission ended, all available missions on my map were back to level 21.

I wish Ubisoft would fix this, maybe just lower the higher-level player's level temporarily and their gear by an equal amount.  The way it is really is the worst of both worlds, he got useless lower level gear and I got killed by a single shot.

Answer (score 2):

The only place you will notice a difference is when you are playing missions on hard.

In the free-roam of New York, levels will not be altered on the NPCs.

In the hard mode missions the level of the NPCs will be determined by the player with the highest level. They will scale accordingly. So it gets really hard for the lower level characters, especially if there is a large difference between your level and theirs.

Normal mode there is a set recommended level that enemies will remain at, with a small variation of maybe one level.

Comment: This seems incorrect based on my play experience. When I go back to early areas to gather collectibles, the enemies are significantly higher level than when I was there the first time. At level 18 I was helping a friend of mine at level 7 catch up, and the enemies we were facing were level 13 in areas that should have been under level 10. I noted that (18+7) = 12.5, which is about 13.

Comment: Yea NPCs and any level or enemies are usually stacked for the highest party member. They get the extra XP though.

Comment: Just run them through high level hostage rescues so the story isn't spoiled. They'll level up faster. But make med kit drops. As alll they'll be able to do is cover and hide as you take care of the enemies. I hear UniSoft is already making game changes as this is a game that's meant to be played for years

Comment: @DCShannon Confirmed. Me (30) and a friend (17) did a lv14 mission on normal difficulty and the enemies were lv25.

Comment: I've never found an enemy more than 5 levels less than my level

Comment: This answer is not accurate.  NPC levels are adjusted for group/individual difficult both in Free Roam and in missions.  Even on "normal mode" the mission's NPC levels will be adjusted to more closely correlate to the average player level of the group.